# Android, location Service in the background

Tags: android, google-api, location

There are tons of so threads on this topic and I've read Google's documentation  and other stuff but still it's not clear for me how it is possible to get location updates, **forever**.

*What I need*: to know where a user is NOW (means: range 5-10 minutes) so every *5-10* minutes, IF there's a location updated, I need to store the new location in a db, even if the main app is not running.

As far, I've done a never ending service that every 5-10 minutes asks for last location, but this (polling) is, obviously, not good.

Google's latest [Receiving Location Updates](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) documentation shows how to do it in the MainActivity and nothing more.

The [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), suggested by Google, "*handles asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand*" so it doesn't seem to be a right candidate.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was "*how to start the service after booting*", so I've solved in the following way:

- created a Service with a LocationListener. It returns
  `Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from the onStartCommand method.
- created a BroadcastReceiver that starts the Service after ther boot
- in the manifest, moved `android:installLocation="auto"` to
  `android:installLocation="internalOnly"` to make the BroadcastReceiver
  work 
  ([doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot))

Still, if the user closes the app from the settings (`Force close`), the service will stop working but this is what the user wants so, no problems.